# Chrome.* API calls in the chrome dev console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, console.log

I was wondering if it is possible to use chrome.* API calls in Chrome's dev console?
When I try to type something like:

```
 chrome.system.cpu.getInfo(function(info){       
       console.log(JSON.stringify(info));   
 });
```

I get the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'cpu' of undefined"

Comment: Apparently not, as `chrome.system` is not defined in the console

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible - if you do it in a context of an existing extension and not in a page context.

First off, make sure that the extension in question has access to the API in question. For your example, the extension needs to have `"system.cpu"` permission.

Then, you need to do any of the following:

1. Open the Dev Tools of the extension's background page, from `chrome://extensions` with Developer mode enabled.
2. Open an extension's own page, i.e. an options page, a popup or something similar, if it has any. You can access a popup's Dev Tools by right-clicking it and selecting "Inspect popup".
3. Open Dev Tools for a page that already contains a content script injected by the extension. Then, go to Console tab, and in the dropdown at the top select the extension's context instead of `<top frame>`. Please note: you'll get the same API access level as a content script, which [is limited](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and does not contain `chrome.system`.